# Adding NON duplicate elements to an expandable array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add elements of type ENTRY in this array. But before adding I want want to make sure its not a duplicate as I don't want duplicate entries. Tried a lot but it keeps doesn't add entries :/ I tried BREAK from the IF clause as well didn't seem to work. Is there something really silly I'm missing  ? Would really appreciate if someone could help me. Cheers

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PhoneDirectory {
    private Entry[] ar;
    static int index = 0;

    public PhoneDirectory() {
        ar = new Entry[0];
    }

    public PhoneDirectory(Entry[] ent) {
        ar = ent;
    }

    public boolean addEntry(Entry ent) throws NullPointerException {

        boolean newEntry = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {

            if (ar[i] == ent) {
                newEntry = false;

            else 
                newEntry = true;
        }

        int length = ar.length;
        Entry[] temp = new Entry[length];

        for (int x = 0; x <= length - 1; x++) {

            temp[x] = ar[x];
        }

        length++;
        ar = new Entry[length];

        // add the new entry in the last index
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            if (newEntry == true) {

                ar[i] = ent;
                newEntry = false;
                // return true;
            } else {

                // ar[i] = temp[i];
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your If block braces are not balanced. please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Set` , dynamically add the data and maintain uniqueness

```
Set<Entry> entries = new HashSet<Entry>();
//note you will have to implment `equals()` & `hashcode()` in `Entry` class
//and then simply
entries.add(entry1);
entries.add(entry2);
entries.add(entry3);
```

It grows by it self you don't need to handle it + it maintains uniqueness,

If you want to preserve the order in set then you need to use `LinkedHashSet`

In your code

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {

        if (ar[i] == ent) {
            newEntry = false;

        else 
            newEntry = true;
    }
```

you are comparing two objects so you need to override `equals()` in your `Entry` class and then you need to use `ar[i].equals(ent)` to check (and not the `==`)

also ,
For example ent matches with value at index 2 and array is of size 4 then at last index `newEntry` would be set to true and so it will allow this entry,  Use `break;` when you find the already existing entry

Comment: I know I can use java collections but I'm suppose to do this by Array only. I did try the break but seems like something else is wrong too which I cannot seem to find.

Comment: Check the brackets of yoru if block

Comment: One should be using .equals method for comparing and not == . Please correct your answer.

Comment: I corrected the equals methods. I have problem with null entries... I mean when I initialise it the postion (0) has a value of null and I think it creates the problem for addEntry method

Answer (score 0):

In the addEntry function you created the temp array with all the previous entries in the PhoneBook. Then you reassigned ar as a new array. However, you never repopulated the new ar with the previous entries you stored in temp.

```
length++;
ar = new Entry[length];

//copy the temp entries back into the new ar
for (int i=0; i<= temp.length-1; i++){
  ar[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Also you need to add a break in your newEntry loop:

```
boolean newEntry = true;
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {

    //comparing object should use equals
    if (ar[i].equals(ent)) {
        newEntry = false;
        //add break;
        break;
    }
    else 
        newEntry = true;
}
```

I don't think you need a for loop to add the lastest entry

Instead of :

```
   for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (newEntry == true) {

            ar[i] = ent;
            newEntry = false;
            // return true;
        } else {

            // ar[i] = temp[i];
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Try this

```
int i = length-1;

if (newEntry == true) {
  ar[i] = ent;
  newEntry = false;
  return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I did both of these two, but it is still not adding entries to the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
    if (ar[i] == ent) {
        newEntry = false;

    else 
        newEntry = true;
```

You really want:

```
if (ar[i].equals(ent)) {
```

It is unlikely your entries will be == to each, which means the same instance, not just an equivalent object.

Comment: Also, the else clause in this section is completely unnecessary as `newEntry` is assigned a value of true right at initialization; the only way it could be false is if it gets set by the `if` statement.

Comment: if (ar[i].equals(ent)) I fixed it to what you suggested and its giving a NullPointerException. I thought of adding if (ar[i].equals(ent) && ar[i]!=null)  to it see if the entry is empty... ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have overridden the equals method on the Class ENTRY

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {

    if (ar[i].equals(ent)) {
        newEntry = false;
        break;
    }
    else 
        newEntry = true;
}
```

Comment: You mean override ? or just as you have put it? because I did chance the == to EQUALS but nothing changed.